# Dropdown with checkboxes closes when clicking checkbox in Blazor Server-side application

Tags: html, css, blazor, blazor-server-side

My Blazor application has the following dropdown with checkboxes:

```
<div class="dropdown" style="position: absolute; top:0; right:0; ">                
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg dropdown-toggle"   aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Choose Columns</button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="dropdownButton1" >
         <li><label><input type="checkbox" style="height:auto;" @bind="showDepartment"/> Department</label></li>
         [... Numerous other Checkboxes ...]
         <li><label><input type="checkbox" style="height:auto;" @bind="showName" /> Name</label></li>            
      </ul>
</div>
```

Everytime I click a checkbox in the dropdown, the dropdown disappears. I want it to only disappear when I click on the name of the dropdown or when I click outside of the dropdown. Is that possible to do somehow?